# Insert new datas into an existing array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array (
    [1] => 149.00
    [3] => 1166.00
)
```

This array can change on every query.

I should have 12 value in this array (form the 12 months of the year).

How can I run into this array and populate it with the other values ?

---

Expected final array should be:

```
Array (
    [1] => 149.00
    [3] => 1166.00
    [2] => 0.00
    [3] => 0.00
    [4] => 0.00
    [5] => 0.00
    [6] => 0.00
    [7] => 0.00
    [8] => 0.00
    [9] => 0.00
    [10] => 0.00
    [11] => 0.00
    [12] => 0.00
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you have an array of array and not a "flat" one? Would be easier and maybe you don't need this double structure

Comment: What have you tried so far? This problem seems very easy to solve if you just do some basic searching.

Comment: I did not get your question! But if you are asking about (filling) it with some extra values then you may get help from `range()` function.

Comment: @DonCallisto, I can change my first array if it's more easier.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php first example

Comment: @DonCallisto: updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is

```
$yourArray[1] = 149.0;
$yourArray[3] = 1166.0;

$months = range(1, 12);
foreach (array_keys($yourArray) as $month) {
  unset($months[$month - 1]);
}

foreach ($months as $month) {
  $yourArray[$month] = 0.00;
}
```

- With [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) you are basically creating ad array with value from 1 to 12.
- Next `foreach` will loop upon your array keys and unset previously setted months, leaving other without a value. The `-1` part is due to zero index of array
- Final `foreach` will set to `0.00` remaining values